# Match multiple patterns anywhere in string?

Tags: regex

Using regex, it's easy to match a single pattern anywhere in a string. For example, for the string "foo" I could do: `^.*foo.*$`.

However, I can't find any information about matching multiple patterns anywhere in a string, in any order. For example, I'm looking for "foo", "bar", "bat" **and** "baz", **in any order**.

How would I construct a regex for this?

Comment: Must all the patterns be present in the string?

Comment: You need to use positive look ahead. `(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)(?=.*bat)(?=.*baz).*`

Comment: @wu1meng2 OP desires to find all the words in any order. Not any of the words. note that alternation `|` is used to find any of the words and not all of the words

Comment: Please note that I use the word "and" in bold in the original post.

Comment: In your first sentence, `^.*foo.*$` is equivalent to `.*foo.*` and if you just want to know if `"foo"` is present, `foo` is enough. If you don't want to match, for example `"buffoon"`, add word boundaries: `.*\bfoo\b.*` or `\bfoo\b`, depending on requirements. Also, you should make clear what you mean by matching "multiple patterns". If you just mean matching multiple strings you should say that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use positive look ahead.

```
(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)(?=.*bat)(?=.*baz).*
```

Note that you could use boundaries `\b` to ensure that the words are standalone and not part of a compound word

```
(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?=.*\bbar\b)(?=.*\bbat\b)(?=.*\bbaz\b).*
```

Comment: I suggest you remove `(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar)(?=.*bat)(?=.*baz).*` since the latter expression is what is needed. Also, it's not clear why `.*` at the end is needed. Presumably, the OP just wants to know if all strings are present.

Answer (score 0):

> *".. I can't find any information about matching multiple patterns anywhere in a string, in any order. For example, I'm looking for "foo", "bar", "bat" **and** "baz", **in any order**.
>
>
>
> How would I construct a regex for this? ..."*

You can use a *non-caputuring* group and no `^` and `$` syntax.

Here is an example.

```
(?:123|456|789)
```

The following texts will match any of the provided values.

```
abc123abca456bcabcabcabcab789cabcabc
abc789abca123bcabcabcabcab456cabcabc
```

Comment: OP wants to match all strings in a given collection. You have not provided a regular expression that will do that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, _"... matching multiple patterns anywhere in a string ..."_, what am I not understanding?  I shouldn't have provided the pattern?  Oh ... thanks ....

Comment: Using the OP's example, you could provide a regex that matches part or all of a given string if and only if all of the strings, `"foo"`, `"bar"`, `"bat"` and `"baz"` are present in the string, in any order.